# Tips for creating a video-voice-chat application

Tags: c#, java, c++, voip, videochat

I want to create a simple chat application that supports voice and video (something like Skype or Google Talk). I don't want to write everything from scratch, so my question is do you know some good libraries for that?

I stumbled over libjingle (c++) and Smash (Java), both implementing the XMPP extension Jingle. Would you recommend one of those?

Comment: sure: http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/smack/index.jsp

Comment: How did you finally make it??

Answer (score 1):

have a look at freeswitch for the VoIP library. It may come across as a fullon carrier software (which of course it is) but you can include the library in your own software to build client and/or server VoIP applications.

Answer (score 1):

A chat application that is based on P2P connection is difficult to be formed mainly due to NAT firewalls under which most of the users are.

You can study IETF standards like [ICE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interactive_Connectivity_Establishment),[STUN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/STUN), [TURN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Traversal_Using_Relays_around_NAT), [SIP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_Initiation_Protocol) and son on. 
Though implementing these is a herculean task.

But,

[RTMFP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_Time_Media_Flow_Protocol) is an easy solution for implementing P2P voice and video chat app. It is developed by Adobe and can be easily used by any flash developer in his application. Its free and easy to implement.U just need to know flash development for this. Also Study Adobe [Cirrus](http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/cirrus/) and [Adobe AIR](http://www.adobe.com/products/air.html) for desktop apps.

Cheers!!!